# Очередь выполнение функций javaScript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите почему данный код не выводит не ошибки, и в консоль не чего не выводит.

Пытаюсь сделать последовательное выполнение  функций.
Интересно почему именно этот код не работает?
В дебагере он даже не входит в функцию `runF()`.

```
function Queue() {
  Queue.prototype.constructor = function() {};
  this._this = this;
  this.funccollect = [];
}

Queue.prototype.addFunc = function(callback) {

  this.funccollect.push(callback);

  return this;

}
Queue.prototype.runF = function() {
  this.funccollect[1].apply(this, arguments);
}

var queue = new Queue();

queue.addFunc(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Первая функция');
      queue.runF();
    }, 2000);
  })
  .addFunc(function() {
    console.log('Вторая функция');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну а где же вызов-то `runF`?

```js
function Queue() {
  Queue.prototype.constructor = function ()  {};
  this._this = this;
  this.funccollect= [];
}

Queue.prototype.addFunc = function (callback){ 
  this.funccollect.push(callback);
  return this;
}

Queue.prototype.runF = function () {
  this.funccollect[1].apply(this,arguments);
}

var queue  = new Queue();

queue.addFunc(function () { 
  setTimeout(function (){
    console.log('Первая функция');
    queue.runF();
  },2000);
})
.addFunc(function () { 
  console.log('Вторая функция'); 
});

queue.runF();
```

Comment: Все понял ошибку спасибо.

Comment: этот вызов был внутри `setTimeout`. И в твоем решении все еще нет вывода `'Первая функция'`

Comment: @Grundy "В дебагере он даже не входит в функцию runF()." - в моем решении - входит.

Comment: Входит :-) но вызов `runF` уже был, а первая функция так и не выполняется :)

Comment: Незаслуженно забыта `funccollect[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Такие вещи лучше всего делать на базе `Promise`.
Набросал вариацию с поддержкой старомодных `(err, res)` коллбэков.

```js
class Queue {
  constructor() {
    this.list = [];
  }
  pushWithCb(func) { // func(prev, next) where next(err, result)
    this.push((...args) => {
      return new Promise((ok, fail) => {
        args.push((err, res)=>{
          if (err) return fail(err);
          ok(res);
        });

        func(...args);
      });
    });
    return this;
  }
  push(func) {
    this.list.push(func);
    return this;
  }
  run() {
    let p = Promise.resolve();
    this.list.forEach((func) => {
      p = p.then(func);
    });
    return p;
  }
}


let q = new Queue();
q.pushWithCb(function(_, next) {
  next(null, 1);
}).push(function(res1) {
  return Promise.resolve(res1 + 1);
}).push(function(res2) {
  return res2 + 1;
}).run()
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 1):

Кому интересно сделал вот так.

```
function Queue() {
    this.index= 0;
     Queue.prototype.constructor = function ()  {};
     this._this = this;
    this.defferent = [];  
    }

 Queue.prototype.addFunc = function (callback){ 
     this.defferent.push(callback);
        return    this;
    }
 Queue.prototype.runF = function ()
 {
     this.defferent[this.index].apply(this,arguments);
     this.index++;
 }

var queue  = new Queue();
queue.addFunc(function () { 
setTimeout(function ()
     { console.log('Первая функция');
        queue.runF();},2000);
      })
.addFunc(function () { console.log('Вторая функция'); } ).runF();
```

Comment: Другими словами, вы воспользовались решением @Igor?

Comment: @Anon, не совсем, тут появляется сущность index